# DLL conflict when building Sitefinity 9.2 with visual studio

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, telerik, sitefinity

When building an instance of Sitefinity 9.2 using visual studio 2013 I get a DLL conflict error.

*There was a conflict between "Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core, Version=2015.1.225.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7" and "Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core, Version=2016.2.421.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7". (TaskId:7)*

The DLL that is causing the issue is their own DLL

*References which depend on "Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core, Version=2016.2.421.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7" []. C:...\bin\Telerik.Web.UI.dll (TaskId:7)
Project file item includes which caused reference "C:...\bin\Telerik.Web.UI.dll". (TaskId:7)*

The included DLL for Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core is the older version 2015.1.225.40 and not the newer 2016.2.421.40 version.

Is there a way to resolve this in the web.config (like a binding redirect) or some other method? Being that it is a vendor application should they provide the correct DLL version?

Comment: So, in your bin folder you have the older Telerik assembly, aren't you? 
That's the version that comes with Sitefinity 9.2
You have to find what is referencing the newer version - check your references in the project. Also, what version of Feather do you have - some of the feather assemblies may reference newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your references on the SitefinityWebApp project.  In some cases I found that you have to delete the reference and then re-add it back.  Also, if you have other projects part of your solution you will need to check those projects for references to that assembly.

Also, something to look into, Sitefinity will allow you to use NuGet packages to manage the assemblies and project references in your solution.  You can see more details about this at the following link...

http://docs.sitefinity.com/upgrade-a-project-that-has-nuget-packages

Hope this helps.